# how to change "Activate Your Account" message on wordpress activation page?

Tags: php, wordpress

Example: http://undeniable.info/img/temp_ss.png

I am using a user approval system therefore the message saying your account is active is not at all appropriate.  We still want our users to confirm their emails so I want to change the messages "Account Activated" to "Account Email Validated" and "Activate Your Account" to "Validate Your Account Email" or something like that.

```
grep -r "Activate Your Account" *.php
```

searching my entire public_html dir for these account activated messages returns nothing, whether upper or lower case.

Searched the entire wordpress database for these strings as well with no result.

There are these activate.php files which have the activation page and a wp-activate.php file with text from the body of the page that is shown when user click on email link to "activate".  But these templates don't contain that header message that says "Account Activated" like in the screenshot.

Tried clearing wordpress caching system and browser cache. I have no idea where these "Account Activated" and "Activate your Account" messages are coming from and I need to change them.

Theme being used is woffice

Comment: Maybe the message isn't stored in a php file but in some other text file. Try `grep -RIi "Activate Your Account" *` I would bet it's in the database though.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, my grep was wrong...

```
grep -r "Activate Your Account" *
```

\wp-content\plugins\buddypress\bp-members\classesclass-bp-members-theme-compat.php

```
$title = __( 'Activate Your Account', 'buddypress' );

if ( bp_account_was_activated() ) {
    $title = __( 'Account Activated', 'buddypress' );
}
```